# Is it okay to use JPA versioning/optimistic locking to prevent old data from being submitted for modification?

Tags: java, jpa, concurrency, optimistic-locking

I want to prevent the following scenario:

- User 1 brings up a web page that allows him to modify some data
- User 2 brings up a web page that allows him to modify the same data
- User 2 modifies and saves the data
- User 1 attempts to modify and save the data (need to prevent this)

We currently use JPA optimistic locking which gives our Entity's a version number.  Would it be a bad practice to use that version attribute in our business logic to prevent the modification from taking place?

Bonus question: If its okay to use the version attribute, would be it be a bad practice to just allow the OptimisticLockException to occur so the modification fails?  Or is that just being lazy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's essentially what optimistic locking is. Versioning gives you some obvious additional benefits.

Whether you can just rely on `OptimisticLockException` depends on your application. If you're performing a lot of operations before the saving possibly fails, it may make sense to check in advance, i.e. fail-fast (although it can still fail at the end).

In simpler cases there's no reason why you couldn't just wait to see if the exception is thrown, since you'll need to handle it anyway.